# Join elements of an arbitrary number of lists into one list of strings python

Tags: python, list

I want to join the elements of two lists into one list and add some characters, like so:

```
list_1 = ['some1','some2','some3']
list_2 = ['thing1','thing2','thing3']

joined_list = ['some1_thing1', 'some2_thing2', 'some3_thing3']
```

however i don't know in advance how many lists I will have to do this for, i.e. I want to do this for an arbitrary number of lists

Also, I currently receive a list in the following form:

```
list_A = [('some1','thing1'),('some2','thing2'),('some3','thing3')]
```

so I split it up into lists like so:

```
list_B = [i for i in zip(*list_A)]
```

I do this because sometimes I have an int instead of a string

```
list_A = [('some1','thing1',32),('some1','thing1',42),('some2','thing3', 52)]
```

so I can do this after

```
list_C = [list(map(str,list_B[i])) for i in range(0,len(list_B)]
```

and basically `list_1` and `list_2` are the elements of `list_C`.

So is there a more efficient way to do all this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `join` function like this on the base `list_A`, itself, no need to `split` it for probable `int` values:

```
list_A = [('some1','thing1',32),('some1','thing1',42), ('some2','thing3', 52)] 
["_".join(map(str, i)) for i in list_A]
```

**Output:**

```
['some1_thing1_32', 'some1_thing1_42', 'some2_thing3_52']
```

**Update:**

For you requirement, where you want to ignore last element for last `tuple` in your `list_A`, need to add `if-else` condition inside the `list-comprehension` as below:

```
["_".join(map(str, i)) if list_A.index(i) != len(list_A)-1 else "_".join(map(str, i[:-1])) for i in list_A  ]
```

**Updated Output:**

```
['some1_thing1_32', 'some1_thing1_42', 'some2_thing3']
```

Comment: i already tried this. This will join the elements themselves which is not what I want, i.e. some1_some2_some3 etc.

Comment: @AnarKi, I added the output, is this not same as what you mentioned in `joined_list`?

Comment: This works fine, I actually tried on list_B that's why it didn't work... sorry about that

Comment: One more thing, do you know if the last element of list_A can be omitted sometimes  ? like list_A[:-1],m resulting in this: `['some1_thing1', 'some1_thing1, 'some2_thing3']` without 32,42..

Comment: Thanks, in that case, would you like to upvote and accept?

Comment: `list_A` is static as per your question, you will need to add a condition on what basis you want to ignore last element. Once your condition is satisfied you can use the slice notation to ignore last element

Comment: I tried to `["_".join(map(str, i)) for i in list_A[:][:-1]]` doesn't work, my "condition" is just not to account for the last element no matter what it is

Comment: it works for me, but no need if `A[:]`. just adding `[:-1]` at the end should work, like `["_".join(map(str, i)) for i in list_A[:-1]]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171136/discussion-between-akshat-and-anarki).

Comment: regarding the Update, I wrote an answer that uses your approach combined with another list comprehension. This is quicker than using an `if-else` condition

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you are using python>=3.6:

```
[f'{i}_{j}' for i,j in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

If you using python3.5, you can do this:

```
 ['{}_{}'.format(i,j) for i,j in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

also you can use this if you don't want to use formatted string:

```
['_'.join([i,j]) for i,j in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this apply for an arbitrary number of lists ?

Comment: @AnarKi yes, the below answer, but it was suppose to be over the `zip` object, not `list_A`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga *below* might change with votes or whatnot.

Comment: @AnarKi what do you mean by arbitrary number of lists?  you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

For ignoring the last element of every tuple in list_A, I found this to be the quickest way:

```
["_".join(map(str, i)) for i in [x[:-1] for x in list_A] ]
```

Comment: this will ignore third element for all cases. is that expected?

Comment: yes that is what I wanted, basically exclude the last element of each tuple